# Samba remove Read permission for some users

Tags: linux, samba

I have a directory that is acessable by all the users and in there are some files of a program that i would like to hide or lock for some users and made visible/usable for some other users. Basicly i would like to remove the read option for some users.

Is this possible and how ? Thank your

Answer (score 0):

Make it only executable, by changing `chmod 100`
if u want to hide file use .(dot) begining of file name

**Ex : .foo.txt**  this file will be hide

Comment: thank you but only a group of people can execute it the other group cant